# static-ip + huawei-lte-stick e3372 with dhcp + ipsec vpn?

Tags: static-ip, vpn

I have the huawei E3372 LTE Surf Stick for internet access connected to a raspberry pi 4 with raspbian os. The internet connection works, the stick creates an network interface "eth1" which gets a ip 192.168.8.103 over dhcp from the stick, the sticks gateway pre configured ip is 192.168.8.1 and it is not possible to change that.

What i actually wanted, is a static ip on my raspberry (192.168.64.48/29) to connect it with strongswan network to network over an ipsec vpn tunnel to the destination network. I wanted to use a fixed ip, so i can make firewall rules on the destination side only allowing this specific ip.

I'm no networking expert, but i hope i descriped what i want to achieve. I got the tunnel working, but only with dynamic ip, e.g. my source ip being 192.168.8.103. What do i have to do to achieve the connection over the internet with a static ip and subnet i define?

I read a lot over bridging, forwarding but don't really know how i can achieve this.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to get a static IP in stead of the dynamic IP assigned by the huawei E3372 LTE Surf Stick? I don't think this is possible. Your Internet Service Provider has to do it. This is not likely to happen when you get your Internet from a mobile network.

Comment: No, i want to get a private static ip with a subnet mask i choose  (i.e. 192.168.64.48/29), not a public static ip. But if i change the (private ip from the lte stick dhcp: ) 192.168.8.103 to .64.48, i am not able to use the Internet connection? Do i need a bridge?

Comment: I don't think this can be done, as the Huawei stick is assigning the IPs and you can't change the subnet mask used by the stick.

Comment: Sure i am not overseeing something obvious? Can i workaround this with a bridge interface?